# Where has my Windows Phone emulators gone in VS 2013 Update 2?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 installed, when I go and create a universal app I have the ability to run the Window 8 version either on the local machine or a simulator. But with the Windows Phone version I can only run it on a physical device - no emulators/simulaotrs are listed as options.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: are you sure that you installed the WP SDK?

Comment: The Phone emulator requires a Hyper-V enabled machine.  Are you certain your machine supports the baseline requirements for Hyper-V (you can see those on the SDK requirements).  Is Hyper-V running on the machine?

Comment: What platform are you building for? The emulator is x86 and physical devices are ARM, so if you aren't targeting AnyCPU then only one will be available. Change the build target to get the other.

Comment: @JeffSanders-MSFT I'm developing on a virtual machine that runs Windows 8.1, 64bit, and has 4GB of RAM available. So my guess then is that it's the Hyper V that's the problem. Now to find out how to enable that on a virtual machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running on a Virtual Machine.  You cannot run Hyper-V on a virtual machine so your only option will be a Physical Device to test your work on.  You could also move to a physical machine that meets the requirements for running the emulator listed in the Phone SDK requirements here.
"For the Windows Phone emulators, Windows 8.1 (x64) Professional edition or higher, and a processor that supports Client Hyper-V and Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)"  From: http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-professional-with-msdn-vs#Fragment_SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to upgrade Visual Studio to the latest update which is 3:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43721

Also there have been a few emulator updates as well. I guess it won't hurt to install them:

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk

I think updating everything to the latest version is the way to go here. If nothing helps, try reinstalling the Windows Phone SDK. I did that the last time my emulators went missing..